# PHP: If statement in variable declaration

Tags: php, variables, variable-assignment

I know that in a language like C# you can use an if like statement (I know these have a name but cannot remember what it is called) kind of like this:

`var variable = this ? true : false;`

(I understand that won't be correct, but it's been a while since I have done them, please correct if wrong).

My question is thus: **can you do the same kind of thing in PHP, if so how?**

***(The site has been built in WordPress but this is a question about generic PHP variable assignment over wp_* functionality)***

I want to be able to declare a variable as such :

```
$current_user = if (is_user_logged_in()) {
    wp_get_current_user();
} else {
    null;
}
```

and I wondered how I would go about making this a single line variable decloration?

Comment: its the same concept of ternary in PHP, `$var = (condition) ? true: false;`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's called [Ternary operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary) and you can use it in a different set of ways, one way is like so:

```
 $cake = isset($lie) ? TRUE : FALSE;
```

The `isset(...)` can be changed out with any validating / checking operation that you want and the `TRUE : FALSE` can be replaced with values / variables.

Another example:

```
$cake = ($pieces < 1) ? $cry : $eat;
```

Answer (score 1):

It's called ternary operator.
In PHP the syntax is almost the same:

```
$current_user = (is_user_logged_in() ? wp_get_current_user() : null);
```

Comment: Actually it is called a "ternary"..

Answer (score 0):

Ofcourse you can do that in `php` also. Try this -

```
$current_user = (is_user_logged_in()) ? wp_get_current_user() : null;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$var = 4; // Initialize the variable
$var_is_greater_than_two = ($var > 2 ? true : false); // Returns true as 4 is greater than 2
```

May be this helps, its a ternary operator